# How to trigger a pickerview when select a cell in a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a tableView with 7 cells like this:
[image]

I wanna trigger some events when you select a cell. For example, start editing the username when you tap the Username row. And pop up a picker view at the bottom with Male/Female selection inside when you tap the Gender row.
As far as I know, I need to put those events inside this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

But I have no idea how to accomplish this. Anyone has ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Putting the logic in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is a good way to go.

How you do it is to write code. There is no stock answer.

If you want content to appear on top of the current window then you will need to handle that yourself. On iPad, you could use a popover, but popovers are not supported natively on iPhone/iPod touch. You might look at using a 3rd party popover library that offers popover support for iPhone. There are several on Github, and probably several on Cocoa Controls as well. I've used one before, but it had a few issues, so I wouldn't recommend it.

If you are ok presenting a whole new view controller then simply define a new view  controller in your storyboard, give it a unique identifier, use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to create it, then `presentViewController:animated:` to display it modally.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can make each cell has its own picker view.

```
open class DatePickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  let picker = UIDatePicker()

  open override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
  }

  open override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
  }

  open override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
  }

  open override var inputView: UIView? {
    return picker
  }
  ...
}
```

And then in your `didSelectRowAt`, just make the cell `becomeFirstResponder`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DatePickerTableViewCell {
  if !cell.isFirstResponder {
    _ = cell.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
 }
}
```

You can check my library for detail: 
https://github.com/hijamoya/PickerViewCell

Comment: By far the best answer to this question.

Comment: thanks, feel free to give any suggestion to my library.

Answer (score 0):

`UIPickerView` is subclass of `UIView`, so you can add and use it same like any other `UIView` object. for your specific recquirment you should create an object of `UIPickerView` and show and hide it when necessary.
So create a `UIPickerView` and add above the table view inside view in which you added tableView and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` set `pickerView.hidden = false`

And also you can animate it from bottom via

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
            // And set final frame here
        })
```

Comment: Doing animations by setting the view's frame isn't reliable in Auto-Layout. Usually you need to use a constraint, change the constant on the constraint, and then call layoutIfNeeded inside the animation closure.